# How to pass output of previous Lambda function to next Lambda function when current Lambda function fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

**How to pass output of previous Lambda function to next Lambda function when current Lambda function fails?**

I have three Lambda Functions L01, L02 and L03.

Following is my **Step Function Definition**:

```
{
  "Comment": "Recovery Plan",
  "StartAt": "L01",
  "States": {
    "L01": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:XXXXX:function:Lambda01",
      "Next": "L02"
    },

    "L02": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:XXXXX:function:lambda02",
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": ["States.TaskFailed"],
          "IntervalSeconds": 1,
          "MaxAttempts": 3,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "Catch": [ {
      "ErrorEquals": [ "States.TaskFailed" ],
      "ResultPath":"$",
      "Next": "L03"
       } ],

      "Next": "L03"
    },
    "L03": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:XXXXX:function:lambda03",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

**Following are inputs and Outputs of Lambda Functions**:

Output of L01 is

```
{
    "k01": "v01"
}
```

Input to L02 is from L01 i.e.

```
{
    "k01": "v01"
}
```

Output to L02 is

```
{
    "k01": "v01",
    "k02": "v02"
}
```

Input to L02 is from L01 i.e.

```
{
    "k01": "v01",
    "k02": "v02"
}
```

Output of L03 is

```
{
    "k01": "v01",
    "k02": "v02",
    "k03": "v03"
}
```

My Lambda Function L02 is failing. I want to execute state machine in fail case also. I want to pass input of L02 function to the input of L03 function when L02 fails and want to add one key as `error` with value `custom error`.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Specify `ResultPath` property in the error catcher. By default it is `$` (and you're specifying it explicitly), which means that output of a failed State will be only error info (with code and optional cause). However, if you set `ResultPath` in Catcher to, for example, `$.error_info` then you will preserve state and error data will be accessible under `error_info` property (other properties won't be modified).

For more details, you may be interested in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html (Error Handling).